# Spring-Cloud-Config with bare local repository

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I need to use a spring-cloud-config-server in an environment which does not have access to the configuration git-repo.

We setup a Jenkins Job which mirrors (`git clone --mirror`) the repository to the cloud-config-server (/opt/foo.git) and now I want to use this as source.

My first idea was to use

```
uri: file://opt/foo.git
```

But this fails with

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: No .git at file://opt/foo.git
```

Moving the bare repo to a subfolder .git does not work either. So I did some research and spring-cloud-config server does seem to have a special handling for all `file:`prefixed urls which prevents cloning this repository.

My current workaround here is a that I created a new local repository `/opt/foo2` which has `/opt/foo.git` as remote.

Any call from spring-cloud-config-server now access `/opt/foo2` and if any update in `/opt/foo.git` exists updates the local repository. Works but kinda feels dirty...

Do you see any other option for this use case which does not involve having a local webserver serving the git mirror? ;)